# Can I send funds from my stripe account to another stripe account without using the recipient's credit card number?

Tags: stripe-payments

Can I send funds from my stripe account to another stripe account without using the recipient's credit card number? In my website, I want the admin to transfer funds from his account to the user's stripe account (not the user's bank account). User's stripe account info will be stored on registration to my site. If there is a way to transfer funds in this way, please share it with me.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: did you find any solution for this then kindly please guide me a little bit  i also want to implement the same process to.

Answer (score 7):

As I understand it you can't do exactly as you wish (i.e. transfer money from one Stripe account to another) but you could take a look at Stripe Connect which allows you to collect payments on one of your user's behalf. The money will then be paid into their Stripe account minus Stripe's fees and your own (if any).

See here for further info:

https://stripe.com/docs/connect